# Can an enemy still be attacked in mid air?

Tags: dota-2

Recently I have seen players, playing as Tiny for example, attacking the enemy after using *toss*. This throws an enemy up into the air, and then deals damage to them once they land.

I've tried to do the same thing, but I can't seem to deal any damage to the enemy once they're in the air.
Is this due to the update recent patching mid-air damage? If not, then how would I damage enemies in the air it?

Answer (score 3):

**Units do take damage when tossed.**

However in your case the "tossed" hero moves outside the attack range of tiny and thats why you wern't able deal damage. If a ranged hero were attacking a unit which is then tossed, it will continue attacking unless it moves outside the attack range. 
Another way to damage tossed units is by using targeted spells and some non targeted ones too.

Note: Even if the unit dies mid-air it still deals area damage wherever it lands.

[**Tiny Wiki**](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Tiny)

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can damage an enemy in the air they are not invincible or invulnerable while in the air depending on the cause of whatever placed them into the air.

Both Tiny, Rubick, Tusk and multiple heroes having enemy in the air using a skill and you can still attack them unless they are outside the attack range of the hero or the hero has such a slow attack speed that the normal attack cannot connect to the unit while in the air.

Tiny using toss allows him to use his avalanche on the tossed unit or hero increasing the damage done to the unit or hero.

Stuns like the one from Sandking, Lion, Nyx Assassin will also throw the enemy unit into the air and you can still attack them.

Also there is this skill of Earthshaker to jump when the hero has an aghanim's scepter and uses the Enchant totem skill and Earthshaker could still be attacked in the air.  (It's funny to see Earthshaker land in a heap when he dies in the air)

Here are some of the skills that will make you invulnerable when you are in the air (damage is only from the skill itself, no way to damage the hero while under the affect of any of those spells):

- Invoker's Tornado -> damage after you land but none while in the air.
- Eul's Cyclone -> no damage if you're the owner, but deals 50 damage if it's used by an enemy, this means that Eul can stop enemy blink daggers.

  [Cyclone]: A target unit is swept up in a cyclone and made invulnerable for 2.5 seconds. Cyclone can be cast on self. Enemy units take 50 damage upon landing.

  Range: 575

  Cooldown: 23 Seconds

  Manacost: 175 Mana

  You cannot cyclone allies

  Double clicking the item uses Cyclone on yourself

  Cyclone is a Normal Dispel, therefore it can dispel certain debuffs such as Dust of Appearance. (More on Dispel)

  Meat Hook can stop the cyclone and pull the units without damaging them

  Is blocked by Magic Immunity when using on enemies.

  Is blocked by Linken's Sphere

  Can be Purged

I don't know of any other skills or items that can make you go up in the air yet.

Comment: A couple of patches ago eul's was reworked. Units take 50 magic damage upon landing. So you cannot blink away now.

Answer (score 1):

Previous answers do mention this important fact that you can attack/deal damage to a unit if it is in mid-air.

Also you mentioned that you are not able to deal as much damage to a unit in mid-air rather than on land.

If you were referring to magical damage inflicted by spells or items, then you will deal damage onto the unit as long as you have successfully cast the spell/item onto the targeted unit.

If you were referring to physical damage inflicted onto the unit by your unit(s), then the number of physical hits onto the unit does mather.
If you have issued an auto attack onto the targeted unit immediately after tossing the unit into air, then the number of "hits" you have landed onto the unit is definitely equivalent to the possible number of "hits" within the period. I will suggest you to turn on the "smart attack" function in options to prevent miss clicks.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is attacking a tossed target, wich is possible and no, it doesn't deal damage upon landing, but right after the attack hits.

There are two ways to do this, one of them is impratical and almost impossible:

- Toss, try to rightclick the moving target. (impratical way)
- Toss, A+leftclick (this will issue an attackmove).

As someone alredy suggested you could try the smart attack move to ease things a bit.

If you have an *echosabre* it will also proc and give you two attacks, same apllies to all UAM (past UAMs included i.e. Diffusial Blade) and Lifesteal sources